# uicollectionview cells are changing size after being displayed during transitions

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, animatewithduration

Currently i have a chat app utilising a collection view with a input accessoryView at the bottom to type in your messages.  when the user types inside the textView, the keyboard is displayed and also dismissed by tapping outside the textView or interactively dismissing the keyboard.

the problem is that when the keyboard is dismissed, the collectionView cells (which contain the messages) correctly move to their new position, however they grow horizontally as they appear with that growth visible to the user.  I have identified that this effect occurs during the keyboard animation which I require. Just don't know how to have the collectionViewCells resize in a way that is not visible.  The following is the code I am using for the keyboard transition.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> ```
> UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
> self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect.size.height, 0)
> self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect.size.height, 0)
> })
> ```

I think I may need to either invalidate the collectionView layout or layoutIfNeeded but not sure where to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that the cells grow *vertically* to fill the space that was left by the keyboard?

Comment: And what value do you get for `intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect`? Usually you just need the keyboard's dimensions; the window's dimensions won't matter.

Comment: I am using the correct value for intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect and vertically everything is fine and the sizing is correct.  they only grow horizontally

Comment: when i return the size in sizeForItemAtIndexPath i don't specify the width specifically.  I just return: self.collectionView.frame.size.width for the width

Comment: i had a similar problem when the view first appears but putting collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() in viewWillAppear solved that.  was hoping for a similar fix to this.

Comment: after considering your post I think maybe the problem is not with the collectionView but actually with the way I am presenting the textView.  I will work on my textView definition and see if it helps